# VirtualBox CentOs installation

Tags: virtualbox

After installing CentOS on VirtualBox, I get a very small window:
[image]

I have tried to install guest addition using the following commands, but the window is not changing:

yum install dkms
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install kernel-devel

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you've got a 4K screen and what you're looking at is a VGA console which normally has a 640x480 resolution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127796/discussion-on-question-by-andrey-ramnikov-virtualbox-centos-installation).